# How to separate elements?

Tags: python, methods

```py
from matplotlib import style

print(plt.style.available)
```

**Output:**

```
['seaborn-dark', 'seaborn-darkgrid', 'seaborn-ticks', 'fivethirtyeight', 'seaborn-whitegrid', 'classic', '_classic_test', 'fast', 'seaborn-talk', 'seaborn-dark-palette', 'seaborn-bright', 'seaborn-pastel', 'grayscale', 'seaborn-notebook', 'ggplot', 'seaborn-colorblind', 'seaborn-muted', 'seaborn', 'Solarize_Light2', 'seaborn-paper', 'bmh', 'tableau-colorblind10', 'seaborn-white', 'dark_background', 'seaborn-poster', 'seaborn-deep']
```

I want to separate every element with ',' so that I like to get like this :

```
seaborn-dark
seaborn-darkgrid
seaborn-ticks
..
..
..
seaborn-poster
seaborn-deep
```

What method do I use for that?

Comment: Just do a bit of digging what options Python offers for string manipulation and toy around with it. As a noob here, also take the [tour] and read [ask], if you wanna.

Comment: Are you just trying to print the list out?

Comment: It's a list so print it element by element with a for statement

Comment: The comma `,` is there because it's separating each element in the list. So you need to create a way to have type of loop that goes through each index of that list. Unless you're trying to make a variable with a multi-line string, you'll have to do something else, which is something you need to clarify.

Comment: The key question: What do you want it separate with "," for? Next step? What want you create with the comma separated result?

Comment: I agree with the other comments here. You need to take a step back and ensure you understand the difference in type between your output and desired output clearly.

Comment: Thank y'all ! Really appreciate it! I'll do it on my own.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the .join() command for that.

```
" ".join(style.available)
```

which will output a string with the desired format you need.

Another way to print each one in a separate line without using a for loop is simply like this.

```
print(*style.available)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a for loop to iterate through the list and print each item.

```
for item in plt.style.available:
    print(item)
```